# Formatting issues with image object-fit and how to add a button in line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple `div` element from javascript and css that contains an image, some text, and a button.

**What I am trying to make**

[image]

**What I am getting**

[image]

1. List item

**Issues**

1. The image `object-fit` attribute is not working. I have tried setting it in various ways as well as using other values. Nothing seems to change.
2. I am not sure how to add another object below the text such that is it aligned like the image above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.className = 'contain';
container.style.width = '100%';
container.style.height = (100).toString() + "px"; // 50 is actually some calculation
container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.body.appendChild(container);

let appIcon = document.createElement('img');
appIcon.style = 'background-image:url("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/87c241_d0d4086e109a41c5b91a6c3d77ec868b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_224,h_224,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/SWNLG.webp")';
appIcon.className = "appIcon";
appIcon.style.width = (100).toString() + "px";
appIcon.style.height = (100).toString() + "px";
appIcon.style.objectFit = 'cover';
container.appendChild(appIcon);

let appDownload = document.createElement('div');
appDownload.className = "downloadText";
appDownload.innerHTML = "SOME TEXT BLA BLA <b>THIS PART IS IMPORTANT</b> BLA BLA";
appDownload.style.width = (window.innerWidth - (100) - 60).toString() + "px";
appDownload.style.height = "200 px"
appDownload.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
container.appendChild(appDownload);
```

```css
.downloadText {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
}

.appIcon {
 display: inline;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Change the file name of your image to have w_100,h_100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `background-size: cover;` because you are using the image as background not regular image:

```js
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.className = 'contain';
container.style.width = '100%';
container.style.height = (100).toString() + "px"; // 50 is actually some calculation
container.style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.body.appendChild(container);

let appIcon = document.createElement('img');
appIcon.style = 'background-image:url("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/87c241_d0d4086e109a41c5b91a6c3d77ec868b~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_224,h_224,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/SWNLG.webp")';
appIcon.className = "appIcon";
appIcon.style.width = (100).toString() + "px";
appIcon.style.height = (100).toString() + "px";
appIcon.style.objectFit = 'cover';
container.appendChild(appIcon);

let appDownload = document.createElement('div');
appDownload.className = "downloadText";
appDownload.innerHTML = "SOME TEXT BLA BLA <b>THIS PART IS IMPORTANT</b> BLA BLA";
appDownload.style.width = (window.innerWidth - (100) - 60).toString() + "px";
appDownload.style.height = "200 px"
appDownload.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
container.appendChild(appDownload);
```

```css
.downloadText {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.appIcon {
  /*display: inline; not needed*/
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: cool thanks :) Any idea how I can add a button below the text? can't seem to figure out how to do that

Comment: change this part `appDownload.innerHTML = "SOME TEXT BLA BLA <b>THIS PART IS IMPORTANT</b> BLA BLA";` --> include a <button> element at the end and wrap the text inside a `p`

Comment: oooh nice idea I'll try it :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe used background-size:cover that makes to do Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.
add style to the

```
.appIcon {
         background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;


     }
```

go to decomantation fro documataion fro w3s 
[descrition fro cover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)